# Random error on return method in Spring application?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I am following this tutorial... https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

Everything works perfectly except when I run localhost, I don't get the employee list show up, only the first name last name and description headings. I believe this is because of this...
[image: error]

Its just a random error on line 21, and I believe it is stopping my Spring application accessing employee list but I am not sure. If you want the source code, it has been copied from this repository...

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/blob/master/basic/src/main/js/app.js

I have tried everything, making a new class, changing it around but the error symbol is there and there's no suggestions on what the error is or how it can be fixed. It's really frustrating me to the point I have resorted to SOF.